# What are the in-universe reasons for the kaiju to be pregnant?

Tags: pacific-rim

In Pacific Rim , one of the kaijus that was beaten by Gipsy Danger was pregnant and have a baby kaiju.

So if these are cloned, whats the purpose of pregnancy?

Comment: Two all-devouring mouths are better than one?  Swarm critters pop up in sci fi from time to time.  Think of it like a biological armored troop carrier.

Comment: When a mommy Kaiju and a daddy Kaiju love each other very much, they have a special hug that makes them feel very happy. That is how Kaiju babby is made.

Comment: @Valorum Do you have pics?

Comment: @SJuan76 - Here you go; https://tinyurl.com/y99wolyn

Comment: Clones are genetically identical to the individuals they're cloned from (unless manipulated, and modulo some minor mutations). So if the original kaiju could get pregnant, why shouldn't their clones be able to as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Parthenogenesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis) is a real-world phenomenon whereby even some vertebrates (fish, amphibians, reptiles, and even birds) have the ability to reproduce asexually. While there are a few different ways this works, in some cases the offspring are effectively identical clones of the mother.

So, it's likely the Kaiju reproduce parthenogenetically, but if you insist it wasn't, then consider that to grow a clone you need nutrients, protection from the elements and a generally nurturing environment. The best place to grow a clone is in the living womb of the species you cloned from.

However, this detail isn't really discussed in the movie - mostly due to the rush towards the climax pushing out any further backstory.

As to the reason *why* this particular kaiju was pregnant - it's possible others were also in early stages of pregnancy, but the damage done to the kaiju masked it; also, as someone pointed out in the comments, if the birth had been successful, there would have been another kaiju to deal with; and the aliens sending the kaiju had just stepped up the game by sending two kaiju through together, so selecting pregnant ones might have been part of the strategy.

Unfortunately, we don't get too much of the aliens perspective (except what we glean via the scientists' entering the drift with the dead kaiju) to make any answer less speculative.

Comment: HorusKol:  Sorry , I  did not mean to be rude, I mean how does the parthenogenesis fit in the universe way of explain the pregnancy, no why you answer that-

Comment: wouldnt say this could be parthenogenesis, since no other kaiju seems to be pregnant as well. This is likely to be a particular case, but then why no other kaiju was pregnant_?

Comment: HorusKol: That's right! We don’t know if other kaijus were the same, then we can not state this was common among them.  I don’t discount these idea but it can not be generalized, and yes the parthenogenesis would fit to explain the baby but it does not explain the reason to be pregnant.